# Cannot remotely connect with SSH - Operation timed out

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I can SSH into my remote Ubuntu 18.04 device connecting to a local IP address, but I can't do the same connecting to my external IP (edit: from inside my local network).

Things I've tried:

- Port forwarding. It's open (using DD-WRT), checked with [CanYouSeeMe](https://canyouseeme.org/). When I try connecting to the wrong port, I get "connection refused", and if I connect to the right IP, I get "Operation timed out", so I think the port is forwarding correctly.
- Trying different ports.
- Checking the firewall. The default one (`ufw`) was disabled.
- Checking `lsof` - it shows sshd is listening on the right port (IPv4 & IPv6, root, TCP).
- Rebooting / restarting the sshd service
- Many different `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` settings. Currently on:

```
Port 3020
PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
GatewayPorts yes
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
X11Forwarding yes
AllowAgentForwarding yes
PermitRootLogin yes
Banner /etc/banner
```

Edit:

```
 % ssh joep@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p 3020 -vvv
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/joep/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/joep/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" port 3020
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 3020.
```

Edit 2: Apparently, it works, but only when my client is *outside* of the network.

Comment: Try connecting with `ssh -vvv user@ip` and then [edit] your question and include the output. That should tell us what's going wrong.